# Decreasing label separator width in IEEETran format

Tags: ieeetran

I'm using IEEE Transactions Latex format (conference). Below is an MWE where it can be seen that the distance between bullets and item texts are too wide to be decent. Can it be reduced somehow?

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}

\begin{document}
\begin{IEEEitemize} \itemsep0pt \parskip0pt \parsep0pt

\item Level 1
\begin{IEEEitemize}
\item Level 2
\item Level 2
\begin{IEEEitemize}
\item Level 3
\item Level 3
\end{IEEEitemize}
\end{IEEEitemize}

\end{IEEEitemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: what you need is `\labelsep=0pt`

Comment: You can set this globaly by `\IEEEiednormlabelsep=0pt`

Comment: @touhami Looks like you should make that an answer.